# How you are handling app versioning server side in Ionic/Angular? - APP_BASE_HREF conflicts with routing

Tags: angular, ionic4

#### Description

I have 2 routes, one for the app module and one for the tabs module.

App routes

app-routing.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  {
    path: 'home',
    loadChildren: './pages/home/home.module#HomePageModule'
  },

  {
    path: '',
    loadChildren: './tabs/tabs.module#TabsPageModule'
  }
]
```

Tabs routes

tabs.router.module.ts

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: TabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            loadChildren: '../tab1/tab1.module#Tab1PageModule'
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  }
]
```

On server side, I have a folder per version (v0.0, v0.1 ... v1.3 ...). I set up a default behavior in order to redirect on a version.
Ex: my.app.com/home -> returns the default version in the folder v1.3 for instance

Have you already solved this issue?

I have tried to solve this issue with the APP_BASE_HREF (https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF), but it's not really working ...

### My Environment

```
**Angular Version:**
@angular-devkit/build-webpack     0.13.8
@angular-devkit/core              7.3.5
@angular-devkit/schematics        7.3.5
@angular/cli                      7.3.5
@angular/compiler                 7.2.2
@angular/compiler-cli             7.2.8
@ngtools/webpack                  7.3.8
webpack                           4.29.0
```

So in my index.html, I have deleted the `<base href="/" />` tag and put a script instead :

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    let firstPathname = window.location.pathname.split('/')[1]
    console.log(firstPathname)

    let regexVersioningTag = new RegExp("^v");
    let result = regexVersioningTag.test(firstPathname);
    // if there is a version number
    if(result){ window['_app_base_href'] = '/' + firstPathname; }
</script>
```

So if there is an app version in the URL, the script stores it in a global variable.

In the app.module, I set the APP_BASE_HREF to the global variable or, by default, to '/' :

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent],
  entryComponents: [],
  imports: [
    IonicModule.forRoot(),
    IonicStorageModule.forRoot(),
    AppRoutingModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    StatusBar,
    SplashScreen,
    { provide: RouteReuseStrategy, useClass: IonicRouteStrategy },
    { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: window['_app_base_href'] || '/' }
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
  schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA]
})
```

When I access to home page, it works like a charm ! (ie: my.app.com/home)
When I access to tabproduct page (ie: my.app.com/tabs.tabproduct), the browser produces errors because it's trying to get /tabs/{scripts.js} (but the page loads).
[Browser errors in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CGOGf.png)

However, the tags scripts in the index.html are good !
[Downloaded files, in the head tag](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UvSZC.png)

Futhermore, the versioning is not event working ! The files are not the versioned folder (path / and not /2.8/)

[Downloaded files in the browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uXN8S.png)

And here a reproduction of the issue http://plnkr.co/edit/TFFPrroSnl5ZJ8xxJOPD?p=preview